# Subtract value from given axis of multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Given are the arrays

```
x_ = np.linspace(-50., 50., 101)
y_ = np.linspace(-50., 50., 101)
z_ = np.linspace(-2 * 228., 2 * 228., 913)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='ij')
```

How can I subtract e.g `100` from the last axis of `z`?
One way is to use a for loop, i.e. something like

```
for j in range(len(x_)):
   for i in range(len(y_)):
      z[j, i, :] -= 100
```

but that seems slow and messy. Surely there is a better way to do it.

Example:

```
test_arr = np.arange(0, 16).reshape(2, 2, 4)

# I want: test_arr[..., idx] -= 10 for all idx in range(4)
# Doing test_arr -= 10 does not achieve that *while leaving the first two axes unchanged.*
```

Comment: when you just do `z - 100`, doesn't it make the expected result?

Comment: `z -= 100` seems to be all that is needed.

Comment: The question is unclear: what does it mean to subtract 100 from the last axis? In general, z will be subtracted from all elements. And the example code with the double for loop ends up doing exactly that: the result is simply z - 100, as other comments indicate.

Comment: Please clarify your intention. You could provide an example with a very simple, short 3Dd array (e.g., 2x3x4, to distinguish the various axes easier); show an input and an expected output.

Comment: Here is a Jupyter notebook showing that the for loop you posted, and the `z - 100` approach are exactly the same. https://gist.github.com/nickodell/3991eeaf8cd8bf69a16e28b052f04ec6 If `z - 100` won't work for you, that suggests that the for loop won't work either.

Comment: Please show an example input array and the expected output array (for that input). 2 x 2 x 4 is reasonably-sized, so you can add it straight into your question. Because your intent is still unclear to me: you can't change values along one axis while leaving the other two axes untouched. Perhaps you mean to only have part of the other two axes changed, but again: that is unclear without a proper example.